# Are there any tools than can inspect the class constructs hierarchy of the window or view?

Tags: cocoa, macos, introspection

I want to see the inner constructs of a special view on Mac, like the class name and hierarchy, etc.

On Windows, we can use the Spy app for this purpose. Is there any app that works similarly for use on the Mac ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for [F-Script](http://www.fscript.org/). Have a look at the F-Script injection service on the [downloads page](http://www.fscript.org/download/download.htm).

Comment: Sadly this does not seem to work on Mavericks but the accessibility inspector did what I needed!

Comment: You can definitely get F-Script working on Mavericks: https://github.com/adamnemecek/FScriptAnywhere

Answer (score 4):

A little more abstractly, you can often use the Accessibility Inspector, which is one of the Developer Tools, for the same purposes. Its intended purpose is for testing your app's accessibility to disabled users, who may be using screen readers (such as VoiceOver) or other assistive software or hardware.

Of course, it won't be able to see into your custom views (if you have any) unless you've [made them accessible](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/).

Comment: +1 Accessibility Inspector is very useful; I couldn't get F-Script Injection to work under Lion.